# Returning error data when pulling an object without throwing an exception?

Tags: c#, error-handling

I have a scenario where I normally retrieve an object, let's call it UserRights.
If everything is fine the object is populated.
BUT if something goes wrong i want to know that something went wrong and why. Normally I'd throw an exception, but I cannot throw exceptions up for various reasons.

I was thinking of adding two fields to the returning object, ErrorCode (int) and ErrorReason (string).
If Errorcode==0 then everything is fine and the object is populated. but if it is not 0 then something went wrong and i need to look at ErrorReason to see why.

The biggest problem i can see with this is that i have to update every single object and it's calls to cater for these extra fields.

Are there any other potential ways of returning error data better that this?

Comment: "The biggest problem i can see with this is that i have to update every single object and it's calls to cater for these extra fields." - How much effort would you expect and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your application architecture, so it is difficult to say for certain but you have some options;

**Option 1**

Define a base class, and then all your other classes can inherit from this;

```
public class MyBase {
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage  { get; set; }

    public MyBase ()
    {
        ErrorCode = 0;
        ErrorMessage = null; // or "";
    }
}
```

Then you limit the effort to only needing to update these IF you have an error.

But you do have to update all of your other classes to inherit from this.  (A pain if you have a lot, then you can use option 2 below)

**Option 2**

If you have only a few places where you return your result, then you can modify your response before you send it.

Define the same class as above, but include an extra property for your response.  Such as this;

```
public object MyResponse { get; set; }
```

Then, when you return your result create an instance of this class.  If you have errors update them and leave MyResponse as null.
Else, put your normal response object in MyResponse and return it.

**Option 3**

Define the same class as above but don't inherit from it.
Change your response so that you return a generic object.

When you return your object, return either the correct object or in the case of errors return only the Error object.

Then your receiving function needs to determine the type of class returned and deal with it.

**Option 4**

You could have separate error reporting.
When you have an error you just a reference number, and log your error somewhere else.

The receiver gets this reference number instead of a result, and then does a look up to determine what the actual error was.

Comment: Option 1 sounds good to me. As I still have to create these classes having a default "success" option actually cuts my dev time, I only have to cater for issues.